# Navigate Between Activities in an ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-tabhost, activitygroup, onkeydown, android-1.6-donut

I'm developing an app which contain `TabHost` ,in one of those tabs i have an `ActivityGroup` , and from this `ActivityGroup`, i launch another `SubActivity` ( let's say that i Launch an `Activity` A ), and until this , everything is OK.

The problem is when i press the **BackButton** ,the CurrentActivity( `Activity` A ) is destroyed, but the ParentActivity( The `ActivityGroup` ) is not resumed , and the app show just a null Window with the Title of My App ( "**My Application Title**" ) .

The Code to launch the `Activity` A from my `ActivityGroup` is :

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView();
this.setContentView(view);
```

and i have `overrided` the method `onKeyDown` like this in my `ActivityGroup` :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onKeyDown");
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
            Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
            Log.i(TAG, current.getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            current.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

but it seems that the method `onKeyDown` is never called because a i didn't get the Log "onKeyDown" displayed.

and the logcat display just this :

```
01-05 11:04:38.012: W/KeyCharacterMap(401): No keyboard for id 0
01-05 11:04:38.012: W/KeyCharacterMap(401): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

what i want is to display the `ActivityGroup` when my `Activity` A is Destroyed.

**NB** : **my app level is 4 :** **Android 1.6** , **so i can't** `override` **the method** `onBackPressed()`

Thank you all  for your help

**-----------------------------------EDIT ----------------------------------------**

I have added the code of my `onKeyDown` like this on my `Activity` A :

@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

```
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
        ParentActivity parentActivity = (ParentActivity) this.getParent();
        parentActivity.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And in my `ParentActivity` , i have :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
            Log.i(TAG, "onKeyDown");
            int len = idOfSubActivities.size();
            String idOfCurrentActivity = idOfSubActivities.get(len-1);
            Activity currentActivity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(idOfCurrentActivity);
            currentActivity.finish();
            idOfSubActivities.remove(len - 1);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

I got the same result , the `Activity` A is stopped , but it still give me the null window with the title of my app , and it doesn't display my `ActivityGroup` (`ParentActivity`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a problem similar to this when I first started experimenting with `ActivityGroup`s. The issue is that you need to place your `onKeyDown()` in your `Activity`. However, you need the `Activity` to have a reference to the `ActivityGroup`. Then, when you press back, just call your own `onBack()` in the `ActivityGroup`.

**(EDIT) Here's a Sample for you**

Below is the stripped down ActivityGroup code that handles navigation and history in my apps. It has been adjusted on the fly, so there might be an error. Notice a couple of finer points.

```
public class MyGroup extends ActivityGroup
{
/** Static Reference to this Group. */
    static MyGroup instance;
/** Keeps Track of the History as a Stack. */
    private ArrayList<View> myActivityHistory;

    @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {//Call the Base Implementation
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the Activity History
        myActivityHistory = new ArrayList<View>();

    // Build the Intent
        Intent _root = null;
    //Lists the Applications
        _root = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    // Send the Index to the Child Activity
        _root.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    // Forward the Extras, if they are there
    // Start the root Activity within the Group and get its View
        final View _view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("App Preferences", _root).getDecorView();
    // Start the History
        addNewLevel(_view);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the instance of the {@link ApplicationGroup} that the child Activity
     * belongs to.
     *
     * @param index
     *  The Group that was passed to the child in the {@link android.content.Intent
     *  Intent} via an Extra (int).
     * @return
     *  <b>ApplicationGroup -</b> The group that this child was assigned to.
     */
    static public ApplicationGroup getGroup()
    {   if (instance != null)
            return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Allows the Child to replace the {@link ApplicationGroup}'s current
     * {@link android.view.View View} with the specified View. This is
     * intended to be used specifically by the Child.
     *
     * @param withView
     *  The View to use for replacement.
     */
    public void addNewLevel(final View withView)
    {//Adds the old one to history
        myActivityHistory.add(withView);
    // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
        setContentView(withView);
    }

    /**
     * Takes the specified {@link android.app.ActivityGroup ActivityGroup} back
     * one step in the History to the previous {@link android.view.View View}.
     */
    public void back()
    {   Log.d("Group", "Back overridden");
        //If there are more than one screen
        if (myActivityHistory.size() > 1)
        {   Log.d("Group", "History called");
        // Remove the most recent View
            myActivityHistory.remove(myActivityHistory.size()-1);
        // Change the View back.
            setContentView(myActivityHistory.get(myActivityHistory.size()-1));
        }
    // Otherwise Exit
        else
        {   Log.d("Group", "Program finished");
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Next is the pertinent code for the Activity:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{//If back was pressed
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {   MyGroup.getGroup().back();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Just make sure that you aren't setting the KeyDownListener to anything funny and it should work fine. :) The changes that I made are because I actually have them in an array of Groups (3 at one time). Essentially, just make the Group a Singleton so you can always have the same instance, and keep an array of your Views so that you have a History. Then reference the History when you click Back or when you add a View.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: please see my edit, i've done what you told me and i got the same result , can you please provide some of your code you talked about ?thanks

Comment: Yes, give me a few hours to grab it. (I'm at work and the application I used it in is at home)...

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , i have used the same concept of the history ..Etc but i will try your method by using the HistoryArray typped with View . tanks a gain , i will try this tomorrow

Comment: thanks to you, i've fixed the problem with my own way , i followed this tutorial and it works great : http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html .

Comment: Doht! For some reason I totally missed the TabHost up there. LOL. My example was modified from a TabActivity with Child ListViews. I'm glad you got your answer!!