# Move back to parent activity from child activity android

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

In my app, I have one tab which includes two activities say 1 and 2. Activity 1 extends ActivityGroup, which has one child activity say A. Now scenario becomes like this,
In first tab --> Activity 1 and its child activity A.
In second tab --> Activity 2. After doing some functionality in Activity 1 of first tab, user moves to child activity A of first tab. Now what I want to do, when user presses back button from child activity A, user should move back to its parent activity 1. How to do that? Below is my code..

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        Intent intentProfile = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
        TabSpec tabProfile = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Profile")
          .setIndicator("Profile", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
          .setContent(intentProfile);

        Intent intentFriends = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
        TabSpec tabFriends = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Friends")
          .setIndicator("Friends", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
          .setContent(intentFriends);


        tabHost.addTab(tabProfile);
        tabHost.addTab(tabFriends);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }


    public void switchTabBar(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab); 
    }
    @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        // Called by children
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        }

}
```

### Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends ActivityGroup {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Tab1.this, Second.class);
                replaceContentView("activity3", in);
            }
        });
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
    {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); this.setContentView(view);
    }

     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
          this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
        }

}
```

### Second.java

```
 public class Second extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
          this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
          MainActivity parentTab = (MainActivity) this.getParent();
          parentTab.switchTabBar(0);
        }
    }
```

### Tab2.java

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    // this.getParent().onBackPressed();
         MainActivity parentTab = (MainActivity) this.getParent();
         parentTab.switchTabBar(0);

    }
}
```

Here I can move to tab 1 from tab 2 on back button pressed. But, I can't move back to parent activity from child activity of tab 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override back button in parent activity and make a call from child. For more info please check this link : [Navigate Between Activities in an ActivityGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741591/navigate-between-activities-in-an-activitygroup)

Answer (score 0):

In Tab1:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() 
    {
      super.onPause();
       finish();
    }
```

in Tab1